# trying to use fl_chart of flutter but when i import it i got this kind of error : Error: 'TextScaler' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, import, fl-chart

Time when trying to **import fl_chart.dart** it through this error

: Error: 'TextScaler' isn't a type.
base_chart_painter.dart:31
final TextScaler textScaler;
^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'textScaler' isn't defined for the class 'MediaQueryData'.
line_chart_renderer.dart:27

- 'MediaQueryData' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart').
  media_query.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'textScaler'.

how can i solve this error

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and using latest version of package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `flutter upgrade` in your terminal to upgrade the Flutter SDK. See the release notes of Flutter here https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes

Answer (score 4):

`TextScaler` was introduced in Flutter 3.16.0 to replace all `textScaleFactor`
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/deprecate-textscalefactor

The package author should have updated the package's sdk constraint to `flutter: ^3.16.0` to support the new `TextScaler`.

You could either update your flutter sdk to 3.16.0 up or use an older version of the package which does not introduce the new `TextScaler`.

Update:
check out the github issue [here](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/issues/1509)

Answer (score 0):

## Error

```dart
 #problem in 0.65.0 not working on flutter 3.13.2 need flutter 3.16    Error: Type 'TextScaler' not found.  TextScaler textScaler,
```

## Fixed by using version  0.60.0

Full example

```dart
fl_chart: 0.60.0
```